# Eslint complaining when using tilde paths for imports

Tags: javascript, eslint

I use my own set of `eslint` rules config for my react-based projects like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    commonjs: true,
    es2021: true,
    node: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  extends: [
    // My extends
  ],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 11,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: [
    // My plugins
  ],
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect',
    },
  },
  ignorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/',
  ],
  rules: {
    // My rules
  },
};
```

But when I import using `tilde paths` such as

```js
import something from '~/components/something'
```

eslint complains saying

```bash
Unable to resolve path to module '~/components/something'. [eslint] <import/no-unresolved>
```

The import actually is correct and it imports fine, but how can I configure `eslint` to stop complaining about the tilde (`~`) import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a resolver alias for the `tilde` using https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-alias.

Example entry in `.eslintrs`

```js
module.exports = {
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      alias: {
        map: [
          ['~', '/user/home/me'],
        ],
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Could you please explain more and let me know how to be able to use both relative imports (`./components`) and tilde imports (`~/components`) so none complains?

Comment: You would map the tilde to your home directory, so eslint could resolve it.  Follow the instructions on the npm package, using `~` as the key, and your home directory path as the value.  I added example to solution

Answer (score 2):

I really like Steven's answer, except I wanted this to work with a relative path to my project.

I used this:

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      alias: { "~": path.resolve(__dirname, "src") },
    }
  }
};
```